# How can I add an LDAP directory to all Outlook profiles? (SMIME directory)

Tags: windows, security, microsoft-outlook, ldap, smime

I need my Windows based Outlook users to be able to look up an SMIME certificate from this [LDAP directory](https://www.globaltrustpoint.com/ldap-webservice-access.jsp)

How can I automatically (via scripting or policy) modify an Outlook profile to include this?

Answer (score 0):

Just open *Account Settings*, go to the *Address Books* tab and click the *New...* button.

Comment: Keyword: automatically (scripting)